# Concatenate a loop from user Input

Tags: java

I need to concatenate output from a loop.  User input will determine for how long it will last. I'm am trying to generate a password with generating a random number and then converting the number into ASCII character (all lowercase characters currently). Instead of having multiple `for()` how is it possible to concatenate the out put into one string based on the user input?

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Password
{
 public static void main (String[] args)
 {
     int randNum=0;
     int min=97;
     int max=122;
     int az=0;
     String b="";
     String c="";
     Scanner in= new Scanner (System.in);
     Random randNumlist= new Random();
     System.out.println("lowercase letters [a]");
     String input= in.next();
     System.out.println(" how many characters (max 14)");
     int input2=in.nextInt();

     if ( input.equalsIgnoreCase("A"))
     {
         while(!(randNum>=96 && randNum<=123))          
         {
             for (int n=1; n <=input2; n++)
             { 
                 randNum= randNumlist.nextInt((max-min)+1)+min;
                 az =+randNum;
                 char p=  (char)az;
                 b = new StringBuilder().append("").append(p).toString();
                 System.out.println(b);
             }
         }
     }
   }
}
```

- Example input: a or A
- 2nd Example input: numbers 1-14

Example output:
a
e
b
h
Desired output: aebh

Comment: Add example input and expected output. Your `for` loop is pointless as it is just **ALWAYS** going to run just once.

Comment: @JavaDevil edited to show examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several points:

1. Your for loop is pointless. You initialise `n` to `input2` then loop until `n == input2` meaning one iteration
2. Your `while` loop is pointless and will only also iterate once as `randNum` is set to between 96 and 123 in the first iteration
3. Declare your `StringBuilder` outside of the loop. Currently you create one for each iteration (which is only once) which means the previous String will be lost. Then in your loop just call the append method.
4. Print after the loop by calling the `toString()` method of your StringBuilder.

So something like this

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder()
//Start Loop
    sb.append("Your character here");
//End Loop
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```